# how to shipping specific woocommerce products or category for specific shipping zone

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Ex: i have 3 shipping zone, zone A, Zone B, Zone C and 3 categories, Cat A, Cat B, Cat C

i want to ship only Cat A for Zone A, must be not available for shipping Cat A for zone B & C.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'specific_products_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
function specific_products_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {

```
$product_ids = array( 11909, 11907 ); // HERE set the product IDs in the array
$method_id = 'wbs:14:0dd3bc79_weight_based_shipping'; // HERE set the shipping method ID
$found = false;

// Loop through cart items Checking for defined product IDs
foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
    if ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $product_ids ) ){
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ( $found )
    unset( $rates[$method_id] );

return $rates;
```

}

i tryed with this code

Answer (score 1):

Use `woocommerce_package_rates` filter to check the shipping zone and product category to remove the corresponding shipping method

```
function specific_products_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    $category_ids = [ 'cat-a' ]; 
    $zone_ids = [ 'zone-a' ]; 
    $shipping_method_ids = [ 'flat_rate:1', 'flat_rate:2' ]; 

    $found_category = false;
    $found_zone = false;

    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_term( $category_ids, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $found_category = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    $zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_matching_package( $package );
    if ( $zone && in_array( $zone->get_id(), $zone_ids ) ) {
        $found_zone = true;
    }

    if ( $found_category && $found_zone ) {
        foreach ( $shipping_method_ids as $shipping_method_id ) {
            unset( $rates[ $shipping_method_id ] );
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'specific_products_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
```